# How much memory does MemoryStream use?

Tags: .net, memorystream

I have got a 2 GB machine. Before running my exe, I have got 1.1 GB free memory. When I run the exe which is only one line you can find below, I am getting out of memory exception.

I am expecting the following line to use something around 600 Million Bytes. Does MemoryStream class use more memory than initalized capacity?

```
MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(600000000);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the following Q&A, it is likely that it is because your EXE is unable to allocate 600 megs of **contiguous** memory. ( I was trying to find something in the docs, this is the best I could come up with on short notice. )

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/1af59645-cdef-46a9-9eb1-616661babf90

> "An “out of memory” error almost never happens because there’s not
>   enough storage available; as we’ve seen, storage is disk space, and
>   disks are huge these days. Rather, an “out of memory” error happens
>   because the process is unable to find a large enough section of
>   contiguous unused pages in its virtual address space to do the
>   requested mapping."

Interestingly, that answer linked to [Eric Lippert's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) blog post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx

Comment: And furthermore, I bet you anything the OP is running a 32-bit system.

Comment: I suspected the same thing, but was unable to come up with any documentation to back up my claim.

Comment: It seems like It is something about limits of visual studio as pointed out in the forum you have linked because when I run the exe outside the visual studio I get no error even when I set the capacity to 1.5 Billion.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the documentation to back up @SethFlowers suggestion (that the application cannot find a large enough contiguous block of memory):

> When you initialize a new process, the runtime reserves a contiguous region of address space for the process. This reserved address space is called the managed heap.
>
> [*Automatic Memory Management (MSDN)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f144e03t.aspx)

Here's some additional explanation of .NET memory usage and how you can profile your application's memory usage:

http://csharp.2000things.com/tag/virtual-memory/